# Which workloads of Visual Studio are necessary for web development in C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2022, visual-web-developer

I am new in ASP.NET web development I have installed Visual Studio with two workloads:

1. ASP.Net and web development
2. Data storage and processing

It takes 10GB space. So my question: are both these workloads necessary for web development in C#? Are there any other workloads necessary for web development in Visual Studio? Any additional individual components that might be required?

Comment: start always with the most basics and if you miss something later its easy to just install components using VS installer afterwards. You be fine with just ASP.NET Web dev.

Comment: ASP.NET Web Dev will do for most things regarding web development.

Answer (score 4):

Strictly speaking, you could use none of the workloads and install the specific individual components you need.  The workloads are just handy bundles of components, with the most commonly expected functionality included (once the workload is selected, it shows optional features - some are selected by default as recommended, and the others are related but entirely optional).

The most minimal installation profile for web development would be this, on the Individual Components tab:

[image: ASP.NET and web development dependencies component]

It would bring in any additional dependencies, but you should expect that some features, especially those shown in tutorials or demos, may not be included.

Comment: For basic web development like create forms and perform crud operations and some MVC stuff  Which individual components should I install??

Answer (score 1):

These components are required for asp.netmvc development:

[image]

You can refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/aspnet/whitepapers/mvc3-release-notes).